# Umbraco installation problem. Can not install starter kit. The key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: installation, umbraco, keynotfoundexception

This is a problem I get when trying to install Umbraco. I know that Umbraco has its own forum, but they have just moved it to another url, and I can not seem to be able to post a question there. So I try here. I know this problem has been reported before, and have tried to implement the solutions other people have reported. But I still can not seem to get it working. I have tried to both use Windows installer, as well as setting up the site myself. Last week I managed to create a site, and install a starter kit. But now I can not make it work. No idea why. I do the exact same steps as last week. I have .NET 4.0, IIS 7 and Windows 7. The Umbraco version is the latest (4.7).

No matter if I use Windows installer, or the binary-package from Codeplex, the installation process works fine until the step when I am presented the choice of installing a starter kit. I press for example the Business Startkit, but then I get the error below. I have given full permission for my application folder in inetpub, to IIS_IUSRS, Network service and Network. I have done the same for C:/Temp folder (as suggested by someone). I am using an app-pool that runs on .NET 4.0 in Integrated mode. I also set it to use Network service. I have also tried to both start off with a blank database, as well as creating a new one. The database gets populated with tables. The folder in inetpub is also filled with all the folders and files that should be there. I have also tried using SQL CE, but with out luck. And I do have a working internet connection.

Does anybody have any ideas on how to solve this? It's getting really frustrating. I think I have tried all the suggestions in the other threads, but I might have misunderstood something, missed some steps, or forgotten some advice. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

The error I get:

Server Error in '/site_development' Application.

```
The given key was not present in the dictionary.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 
[KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.]
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)             +2258321      
   umbraco.cms.businesslogic.datatype.controls.Factory.GetNewObject(Guid DataEditorId) +108
   umbraco.cms.businesslogic.datatype.DataTypeDefinition.Import(XmlNode xmlData) +459
   umbraco.cms.businesslogic.packager.Installer.InstallBusinessLogic(Int32 packageId, String tempDir) +187
   umbraco.presentation.install.steps.Skinning.loadStarterKits.SelectStarterKit(Object sender, EventArgs e) +416
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +113
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +9
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +176
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563


________________________________________
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.237
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to install Umbraco firstly without the starter kit?

If so it maybe an issue with the starter kit itself.

Or get the latest nightly build from Umbraco here http://nightly.umbraco.org/